# Calling ngZone.runTask in ngZone.runOutsideAngular still triggering change detection in other components

Tags: angular, zone

I am trying to run a task after 3 seconds using setTimeout in Angular, but I am trying to do it without triggering change detection throughout the entire application.

I tried running the setTimeout outside of Angular zone and re-enter the zone to run the callback task of the setTimeout. But as soon as I renter the zone, it is triggering the change detection throughout the application

I have this specific code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.ngZone.runTask(() => {
          console.log("SHOULD NOT TRIGGER CHANGE DETECTION IN OTHER DIRECTIVES");
        });
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

for a broader view of the code, I have this stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/runoutside-ng-runinside?file=src/app/app.module.ts

My expectation is as long as I am running setTimeout outside of Angular zone, it shouldn't trigger the change detection. I only want to activate change detection when I reach the tasks inside the setTimeout so that I could **keep the change detection within the component, not throughout the entire app components**. However, currently, as soon as I re-enter the Angular zone, it's triggering the change detection in other components as well.

Answer (score 0):

this.ngZone.runTask is always going to run within Angular, subject to the normal changeDetection strategy. Placing it in a runOutsideAngular doesn't change that.

Comment: Additionally, directly from the Angular documentation: 

Running functions via run allows you to reenter Angular zone from a task that was executed outside of the Angular zone (typically started via runOutsideAngular).

Any future tasks or microtasks scheduled from within this function will continue executing from within the Angular zone.

Comment: I understand that it will run in Angular, but why it's triggering change detections throughout the entire app components.

Comment: Using ngZone.runTask is used to return to the Angular context and trigger change detection. If you want to trigger change detection for only that component then inject a ChangeDetectorRef and manually trigger it for only that component.